# How can one increment a global variable?

Tags: jquery

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/JFCPB/2/)

here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.qNum = 0;
    window.$oClone = $('#pq0').clone();      

    addForm();
});


$('.addForm').live('click', function addForm() {   
    var $clone = $oClone.clone().attr('id', 'pq' + qNum + 1);
    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#pq' + qNum).after($clone);
});
```

I am trying to increment my variable 'qNum' a the end of my function 'addForm'.
This will increment the ID so i can find contents easier later in my project.

I am trying to add a ++qNum; at the end of the function but it is breaking the script, it won't run if i add it.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/JFCPB/3/) is my test that won't work with the changes.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to do `window.qNum = 0;` instead of using `new Number (0);`? (does that even work?).

Comment: @user1082764: your jsfiddle lacks `addForm()` function declaration

Comment: Hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/JFCPB/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var qNum = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    window.$oClone = $('#pq0').clone();      

    addForm();
});


$('.addForm').live('click', addForm);

function addForm() {
    var appendTo = $('#pq' + qNum);
    qNum += 1;

    var $clone = $oClone.clone().attr('id', 'pq' + qNum);
    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    appendTo.after($clone);
}​
```

Declare your qNum outside the document ready call. Then ++ increment it to properly keep track. Also, move addForm outside the click listener and call it like so. Hope it helps.

Copy paste this into your fiddle. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your function in another function's scope. That means that outside the `click` event, the function does not exist.

```
$('.addForm').live('click', function addForm() {   
    var $clone = $oClone.clone().attr('id', 'pq' + qNum + 1);
    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#pq' + qNum).after($clone);
});​
```

Doing something like this instead will help:

```
function addForm() {   
        var $clone = $oClone.clone().attr('id', 'pq' + qNum + 1);
        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#pq' + qNum).after($clone);
    }
$('.addForm').live('click', addForm);​
```